# Date.parse(int) returns true in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I need to check if date is valid and is not number or something like that:

```
 function isDate(date) { 
        return (new Date(date) != "Invalid Date") && !isNaN(new Date(date)) && !angular.isNumber(parseInt(date));
    }
```

If `date` is number this method works right but if `date` is `datetime` i get false because `angular.isNumber(parseInt(date)` is true

for example If this method takes `"1989-02-20T22:00:00Z"` it should return `true` if `"6666"` then `false`

Comment: `Date` can be represented in `milliseconds` so it's a `number`, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: Point to note `angular.isNumber(NaN)` is `true`.

Comment: @chsdk for example  If this method takes  `"1989-02-20T22:00:00Z"` it should return `true` if `"6666"` then `false`

Comment: `angular.isNumber(date)` use without the parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via the following way:

```
function isValidDate(date) {
        var regexp = new RegExp("(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-(0[0-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|([12][0-9]|3[01]))T([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]");
        return regexp.exec(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `&& !angular.isNumber(parseInt(date))` part, it will give you wrong results if `parseInt(date)` returns `NaN`.

You can just use the following:

```
function isDate(date) { 
    return (new Date(date) != "Invalid Date") && !isNaN(new Date(date));
}
```

This will give you the expected results, here are some tests:

```
isDate("1989-02-20T22:00:00Z");
true
isDate("1989-02-20T22:00:Z");
false
isDate("1989-02-20T00:00Z");
true
isDate("1989-02-20E00:00Z");
false
```

Comment: if i send number to this function it will return `true` it is not working for me. But thank your for you time. Solution that i wrote works for me.

Comment: @ArsenAblaev That's because `new Date("6666")` is a valid `date`, if you could just make your function take a `Date` object (`new Date(date)`), and use `date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.getTime())` to chekc if it's a valid `Date`.

Comment: Yes. But i needed to solve particular this behavior, so regex helped me

Comment: @ArsenAblaevNote that `regexp.exec("1989-02-31T22:00:00Z")` will be `true`, where `"1989-02-31T22:00:00Z"` is an invalid date. So using Regex won't be the best way to do it.

Comment: I agree. But users wont type fields like `"1989-02-31T22:00:00Z"` manually to the inputs. These is datepicker to prevent it)